# Page curl in tabbed application (curl all but tab bar)

Tags: ios, mapkit, uistoryboard

Is it possible in a tabbed application to not curl the tab bar?  Ie I have a tabbed application with a map tab and I would like to curl the map to reveal some map options.  When I do this it curls the map and the tab bar.

I am doing this in a storyboard if that helps/hurts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard curl effects are on modalViewControllers, if you use a modalVC it will take the whole screen. You will have to find another way to do the effect.

Have a look at this https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl

*Basically, XBPageCurl can be used in two different ways. It can be used to curl a view and show another view behind it where the user can interact with its elements and then uncurl the view back, pretty much like in the Google Maps app (Simple Curl sample). It can also be used to flip pages like in iBooks, where the user can drag the border of a page and release to flip it or cancel the flip (Page Curl sample).*